# Widget Simulator: ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path

Tags: macos, today-extension

Has anyone come across this error before? Its happening when I run the Widget Simulator on my today extension.

```
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /System/Library/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Widget Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Widget Simulator being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /System/Library/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Widget Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Widget Simulator being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /System/Library/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Widget Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Widget Simulator being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /System/Library/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Widget Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Widget Simulator being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /System/Library/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Widget Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Widget Simulator being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this behavior related to sandboxing. When I enabled sandbox toggle it is disappeared